# I can't not setup maven in yosemite

Tags: maven, installation, osx-yosemite

Please help me, I try to set tup maven 3.3.3 on macbook pro yosemite but wrong. I did it bellow:

1. Download apache-maven-3.3.3
2. Extract it to /usr/local
3. Open terminal and do these follow step:

   - cd /usr/local
   - export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin
   - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25
   - restart terminal
   - mvn -version

But it show error:

> -bash: mvn: command not found.

I am a beginner developer. Please help me.Thanks all

Comment: Maybe post your question on http://superuser.com/ instead of here.

Comment: well, installation of development tools is still in scope of Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0):

To manage java version you can use [jenv](http://jenv.be/)

Edit .bash_profile

```
export M2_HOME=~/Documents/Tools/apache-maven-3.3.1
export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```